# The session state Information is invalid and might be corrupted in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, session-variables, session-state

I am using ASP.Net 3.5 with C#,Development ID:Visual Studio 2008. When I am using

```
Session["FileName1"] = "text1.txt"
```

it is working fine, but then I am using

```
number1=17;
string FileName1="FileName1" + number1.toString();
```

then setting with

```
Session[FileName1]="text1.txt";
```

gives me runtime error

> The session state information is invalid and might be corrupted
>   at System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.Deserializer(BinaryReader reader)

Can anybody solve my problem, when I am using string in the `Session` variable? Remember it works on my development machine (meaning local Visual Studio) but when deployed to the server it gives mentioned error.

[image]

Comment: It works on my local visual studio but it gives error on my server where I am deploying it.

Comment: try `string FileName1="text1.txt" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();` `Session.Add(FileName1, "text1.txt");`

Comment: Could you please include a stack trace of this exception?

Comment: Is it a webfarm or just 1 server?

Comment: @Koen just 1 server..!

Comment: @VaibhavParmar Can you provide your actual string being used to store in `Session` or if you can check whether it is not `corrupted` or null at the time you are adding these values in session .

Comment: @SurajSingh I have already check for the null in my code.

Comment: @VaibhavParmar is there any difference in your session state provider configuration between development machine and the server?

Comment: @KonradKokosa no there is no difference.

Comment: What session state mode are you using (InProc, StateServer, SQLServer, Custom)?

Comment: @MichaelLiu StateServer

Comment: Do you still get the issue if you switch to inproc? Have you tried restarting the StateServer service?

Comment: @geedubb no.i am not able to restart the stateserver it affect all the applications on my server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure the FileName1 variable is not null before trying to access it via the Session[FileName1] syntax...

Here's a link to someone else that was having the same problem:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1069600.aspx

Here's his answer:

In the code, I found the following line:

```
//some code
Session.Add(sessionVarName, sessionVarValue);
//some other code
```

> Apparently, because of some dirty data, there is a time when
>   sessionVarName is null.
>
> Session.Add will not throw any exception in this case, and if your
>   Session Mode is "InProc", there will be no problem. However, if your
>   Session Mode is "SQLServer", during deserialization of the session
>   store, you will got the exception that I got. So, to filter out dirty
>   data, I modified the code to become:

```
if (sessionVarName != null)
{
  //somecode
  Session.Add(sessionVarName, sessionVarValue);
  //some other code
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the reason of your error is

```
xyz = new Guid() is also xyz= Guid.Empty;
```

so when you try to convert to string it's throw error.

just modify you code something like that.

```
Guid guId = System.Guid.NewGuid(); 
string x = guId .ToString();
string FileName1="text1.txt" + x;
Session[FileName1]="text1.txt";
```

Comment: Sorry I modified I am not using Guid I am using integer say "FileName1" + number

Comment: i think your problem in this line---- string FileName1="FileName1" + number1; it will be string FileName1="FileName1" + number1.toString();if you have another query you can ask.

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Session[FileName1] ="text1.txt"; try with this

Answer (score 0):

Check your values before storing them in session they may cause this exception during deserialization of the session store, Filter your data .
Check [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.sessionstateitemcollection.deserialize%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName1))
{
  Session.Add(FileName1, "text1.txt");
}
```

Or check for Invalid characters in your string .

Comment: @VaibhavParmar What's your session-state mode ?

Comment: I have used In-proc session-state mode

Answer (score -1):

You can add the Value into session Like this

```
    string FileName1="FileName1" + number1.toString(); 

if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(FileName1))
{
  Session.Add(FileName1, "text1.txt");
}
```